# false jquery validation followed by true validation makes chrome text area lose focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, textarea

I'm using jquery validation on a form with a text area.  The html in the form looks like this (other fields that validate fine not included):

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" action="/forms/contact_received.php" method="get">
    <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="10" value=""></textarea>
</form>
```

jquery script looks like this:

```
$("#contact").validate({    
    rules: { 
        name: "required",
        email: {required: true, email: true},
        subject: "required",
        message: {required: true}
    },
    messages: { 
        name: "Enter your name", 
        email: {required: "Please enter a valid email address",minlength: "Please enter a valid email address"},
        subject: "it's required",
        message: "Please enter your message in the box above"
    }
});
```

In Chrome, when the user tries to submit while this textarea is empty, my error message appears.

Then when user enters text in textarea, he's allowed to write one character (which appears as red "error" text, then changes to black after 1st character) then the error message disappears, focus on the textarea is lost and the textarea goes back to it's initial width.  User then has to click on the form again to enter the rest of the comment.

How can I make it so that focus on the textarea is maintained after validation returns "true"?

Comment: there is NO  following after  false. done :-) what about your previous question. i told you to put return false.

Comment: Can you use the css class 'required' instead of writing rules in js?  That might be a workaround.  Also, why isn't rules.message==='required'?  Why is rules.message an object?  Maybe changing it to a string will make a difference.

Comment: zod I don't understand what you meant on the last question or on this one.  None of the other jquery examples put return false in the script like that, that's all handled by validate plugin isn't it?

Comment: teddy, I tried writing it in the CSS instead of js rules, it does the same thing. As for rules/message, I had just changed that from a string to an object to see if it would change anything before I copied it into stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  The problem was that I'd set .error{display:block} in the sitewide css.  Maybe I should delete this but a couple people had the same problem in the jquery forums as seen here so it's a legit problem:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-in-chrome-field-loses-focus-on-unhighlight

Comment: I don't know if this counts. It was my mistake.  Mark for deletion if I'm doing the wrong thing here.